# WCF: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation - .NET 3.5 vs. 4.0

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an introduction to "Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation" and I wanted to test to handle the request synchronously. I've created a project with .NET 3.5 (VS 2008) and does not work. As my last idea, I converted the project to .NET 4.0 (VS 2010) and now works.
Does anybody know, why does it not work with 3.5?

Comment: Does not work can mean many things.  Did it throw an error?  Did it not start? What exactly happened when you tried in 3.5?

Comment: The EndXY will be not called

Comment: And there is no exception or error